# looping over array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```
contacts = Array.new(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

And I want to create a loop that will take that array and fill in a field with that array like:

```
while contacts.index[0] < contacts.index[3]
  fill_in('field', with: contacts)
   ...
     contacts +=1
end
```

It tells me I've got the wrong number of arguments

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (4 for 0..2)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you bother to look into the documentation for [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html)?

Comment: Stefan, I did but it was a simple case of getting a little confused otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist a constructor of `Array` that takes a variable number of arguments. You can do it

```
contacts = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
```

And then, you can iterate with the `each` method

```
contacts.each do |contact|
  puts contact
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see where I went wrong now. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me